# How can I set the Attachment file encoding for a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, attachment, system.net.mail

I use `System.Net.Mail` to send out a series of `MailMessage` with `Attachment`.

To do this, I fill a `MemoryStream` with data, using a `StreamWriter` with `Encoding.UTF8`.
I then create an `Attachment` using the `MemoryStream`. I can set the MIME type for the attachment, the file name, the file name encoding, etc. But what I can't find, is how I explicitly set the attachment encoding...

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    //Fill ms with data, using sw

    ms.Position = 0;
    Attachment att = new Attachment(ms, attachmentFileName, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

    MailMessage.Attachments.Add(att);
    SmtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

How/where can I state the encoding of the attached file?

I'm no expert in encodings, so if I'm trying to achieve something completely useless and/or impossible, I'd like to hear it too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Charset` property of the attachment's `ContentType` property to a [valid value](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml).

Answer (score 2):

I found this static method in `Attachment`:

```
public static Attachment CreateAttachmentFromString(
    string content,
    string name,
    Encoding contentEncoding,
    string mediaType
)
```

So this might be the solution:

```
Attachment att = Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(
    Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()),
    attachmentFileName,
    Encoding.UTF8,
    System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
```

It forces you to create from a `string` though, I'd like to see another method which uses just the stream.